# Storing custom info in UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: .net, wcf, security, access-token

I have a WCF service on .NET 4 with a custom UserNamePasswordValidator, secured with SSL and message security.

The UserNamePasswordValidator receives the user name and password and passes it to a stored procedure that returns the valid account token for that user name and password.

My problem is that I don't understand how to access that account token in the actual web service. I suspect that I must be able to add the token to a header somewhere, but OperationContext does not exist yet in the UserNamePasswordValidator and setting it on HttpContext fails with "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."

From my googling, it appears that I must implement either IAuthorizationPolicy or IIdentity, but neither of those will have access to the password.

I would think that many services would take a user name and password and use that to find the relevant account. Am I overcomplicating it, or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity to see if the user is authenticated and then just retrieving the information I needed from the database based on the identity name. That seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to capture additional information (i.e.: your token) at authentication time, you need to implement a custom UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator, not just a custom UserNamePasswordValidator.  See http://www.neovolve.com/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user/ for an example.